# emacs autocomplete background color bug

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

When i start typing something in emacs the autocomplete window shows up but it has a yellow background color. When he is loading a hint, it just shows a yellow stripe until it can find something. Its pretty annoying.

edit:

It seems to have something to do with empty lines. The same color pops up when i just hit enter in completely empty file. I cant find the value to change.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Auto Complete is know to have such issues.  You may want to look at the alternative Company Mode.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried company-mode but it acts exactly the same. The error could be in the extension "popup" - but i couldnt find any wrong configuration there. The error seems to be somewehre else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem.

the whitespace-mode seems to be active for some reasons.
So you need to deactivate it.

I tryed a lot of workarounds to deactivate the the whitespace mode in prelude. The only one really worked for me was to add just this line:

```
(setq prelude-whitespace nil)
```

to the init.el file.

Comment: Indeed it is because of whitespace mode. But prelude doesn't work for me. I have to remove `face` from the whitespace-style, like `(setq whitespace-style '(empty tabs trailing))`